# Корректная сортировка в обоих направления по нажатию на поле?

Tags: javascript, java, mysql, maven, servlet

Всем привет, работая с сервлетами столкнулся с такой проблемой. Мне нужно чтобы при выборе сортировки (имени или цене) она сохранялась на все мои страница. У меня при каждом переходе на страницу формируеться новый запрос в базу, для отображения количества товаров на определенное странице, для первой страницы он выгладит так:

```
SELECT *, COUNT(*) AS 'count' 
FROM product 
INNER JOIN product_category 
  on product.product_category_id = product_category.id 
INNER JOIN company_manufacturer_product 
  on product.company_manufacturer_product_id=company_manufacturer_product.id 
GROUP BY pName 
ORDER BY pName 
LIMIT 6 OFFSET 0
```

если я нажимаю сортировать по имени то после ORBER by pName добавляеться asc, и когда я с первой страницы перехожу на вторую то offset с 0 меняется на 6, что верно, а asc меняется на desc, что неверно, так как меняет мою сортировку товара. Проблема в том, что у меня одно поле для сортировки по возрастанию и при повторном нажатии по убыванию. И я не могу придумать как корректно, совместить эти две фичи. На данный момент я запоминаю тип выбранной сортировки. Как можно усовершенствовать мой код, а то я уже закпиел)?

Мой сервлет:

```
@Override
    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp) throws ServletException, IOException {
        ProductFormExecute formExecute = new ProductFormExecute();
        ProductsForm form = formExecute.executeFormRequest(req);

        List<Category> allCategory = categoryService.getAllCategory();
        req.getSession().setAttribute(ALL_CATEGORIES, allCategory);

        List<CompanyManufacturer> allCompany = manufacturerService.getAllCompanyManufacturer();
        req.getSession().setAttribute(ALL_COMPANIES, allCompany);

        List<Product> allProduct = productService.getProductByParameter(ProductResponseBuilder.filteredProduct(form)); //сдесь я передаю свой сформированый sql запрос в сервис, который достает мне лист товаров, по сформированому запросу
        req.getSession().setAttribute(ALL_PRODUCTS, allProduct);

        if (allProduct.isEmpty()) {
            req.getSession().removeAttribute(ALL_PRODUCTS);
            req.setAttribute(ERROR_PRODUCTS, ERROR_PRODUCTS_MESSAGE);
        }

        int countProducts = productService.getAllProduct().size();
        int productMax = form.getProductMax();

        req.getSession().setAttribute(COUNT_PRODUCTS, countProducts);
        req.getSession().setAttribute(PRODUCT_ON_PAGE_LIMIT, productMax);
        req.getSession().setAttribute(SORTING, req.getParameter(SORTING));

        LOG.debug("Product max: " + productMax + " " + countProducts);
        LOG.debug(productService.getAllProduct());

        req.getRequestDispatcher(PRODUCT_PAGE).forward(req, resp);
    }
```

Мой класс формирования запроса в бд:

```
    Map<String, String> responseMap = new LinkedHashMap<>();
        StringBuilder startResponse = new StringBuilder("SELECT *, COUNT(*) AS 'count' FROM product " +
                "INNER JOIN product_category on product.product_category_id = product_category.id " +
                "INNER JOIN company_manufacturer_product on product.company_manufacturer_product_id=company_manufacturer_product.id");

startResponse.append(" GROUP BY pName");

        if (nonNull(form.getProductMax()) && nonNull(form.getPage())) {
            if (SORT_BY_NAME.equals(form.getSort())) {
                startResponse.append(" ORDER BY pName").append(optional()).append(" LIMIT ").append(form.getProductMax()).append(" OFFSET ").append(form.getPage() * form.getProductMax());
            } else if (SORT_BY_PRICE.equals(form.getSort())) {
                startResponse.append(" ORDER BY price").append(optional()).append(" LIMIT ").append(form.getProductMax()).append(" OFFSET ").append(form.getPage() * form.getProductMax());
            } else {
                startResponse.append(" ORDER BY pName").append(" LIMIT ").append(form.getProductMax()).append(" OFFSET ").append(form.getPage() * form.getProductMax());
            }
        }

private static String optional() { // сдесь я проверяю повторное нажатия на сортировку, чтобы поменять ее, но как сделать, что при переходе на страницу оставалась последняя выбраная
        if (checker) {
            checker = false;
            return " asc";
        } else {
            checker = true;
            return " desc";
        }
    }
```

Класс где я получаю данные с формы и сечу их в поля:

```
@Override
    public ProductsForm executeFormRequest(HttpServletRequest request) {
        ProductsForm productsForm = new ProductsForm();
        int minPrice = checkInteger(request.getParameter(FIND_BY_PRICE_MIN));
        int maxPrice = checkInteger(request.getParameter(FIND_BY_PRICE_MAX));
        int productMax = checkInteger(request.getParameter(PRODUCT_LIMIT));
        int page = checkInteger(request.getParameter(PAGE));
        productsForm.setName(request.getParameter(FIND_BY_NAME));
        List<Integer> categoryList = parseArray(request.getParameterValues(FIND_BY_CATEGORIES));
        productsForm.setCategoryList(categoryList);
        List<Integer> manufacturerList = parseArray(request.getParameterValues(FIND_BY_MANUFACTURER));
        productsForm.setManufacturerList(manufacturerList);
        productsForm.setManufacturerName(request.getParameter(FIND_BY_MANUFACTURER_NAME));
        productsForm.setSort(String.valueOf(request.getSession().getAttribute(SORTING)));

        if (minPrice != -1 && maxPrice != -1) {
            productsForm.setMinPrice(minPrice);
            productsForm.setMaxPrice(maxPrice);
        }
        if (productMax != -1) {
            productsForm.setProductMax(productMax);
            LOG.error(productsForm.getProductMax());
        }
        if (page != -1) {
            productsForm.setPage(page);
            LOG.error(productsForm.getPage());
        }

        return productsForm;
    }

    private List<Integer> parseArray(String[] categories) {
        List<Integer> list = new ArrayList<>();
        if (Objects.nonNull(categories)) {
            for (String category : categories) {
                list.add(Integer.parseInt(category));
            }
        }
        return list;
    }

    private int checkInteger(String value) {
        if (value != null) {
            try {
                int parsedValue = Integer.parseInt(value);
                if (parsedValue >= 0) {
                    return parsedValue;
                }
            } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
                LOG.debug("Wrong number format of input parameter.");
            }
        }
        return -1;
    }
```

Моя jsp:

```
<form action="products" method="get">
                    <li><b>Items on page : &#8199;</b></li>
                    <li><a href="${baseURL}/products?limit=6"
                        <c:if test="${productMax == 6 }"></c:if>
                        >6</a></li>|<li><a href="${baseURL}/products?limit=12"
                        <c:if test="${productMax == 12 }"></c:if>
                        >12 </a></li>|<li><a href="${baseURL}/products?limit=24"
                        <c:if test="${productMax == 24 }"></c:if>
                        >24</a></li>
                 <select name="sort" style="margin-left: 600px;">
                         <option selected disabled>Sort by</option>
                         <option value="price">By price</option>
                         <option value="name">By name</option>
                 </select>
             </div>
             <div class="fashion-section">
                 <div class="fashion-grid2">
                 <div id="error_products" style="color: #ff0000">${error_products}</div>
                     <c:forEach items="${sessionScope.allProducts}" var="products">
                     <div class="col-md-4 fashion-grid">
                         <a href="single.jsp"><img src="images/product/${products.imageName}" width="250" height="350" alt=""/>
                             <div class="product">
                                 <h3>PRODUCT NAME:</h3>
                                 <h3>${products.name}</h3>
                                 <p>${products.size}</p>
                                 <p>${products.color}</p>
                                 <p>${products.category.name}</p>
                                 <p>${products.manufacturer.name}</p><br></br>
                                 <p><span></span>${products.price}</p>
                             </div>
                         </a>
                         <div class="fashion-view"><span></span>
                                    <div class="clearfix"></div>
                                 <h4><a href="single.jsp">Add to cart</a></h4>
                         </div>
                     </div>
                         </c:forEach>
                     <div class="clearfix"></div>
                 </div>
             </div>
         </div>
         <div class="col-md-3 side-bar">
              <div class="categories">
                    <h3>CATEGORIES</h3>
                  <ul>
                        <c:forEach items="${sessionScope.allCategories}" var="category">
                                <li><label>${category.name}</label><input type="checkbox" name="categories-checkbox" value="${category.id}"/></li>
                        </c:forEach>
                    <h3>MANUFACTURER</h3>
                            <c:forEach items="${sessionScope.allCompanies}" var="company">
                                <li><label>${company.name}</label><input type="checkbox" name="manufacturer-checkbox" value="${company.id}"/></li>
                            </c:forEach>
                  </ul>
              </div>
              <div class="sales">
                 <h3>SALE</h3>
                 <div class="pricing">
                     <h4>Price range</h4>
                     <input type="text" id="price-form" name="price-form" placeholder="price from" />
                     <input type="text" id="price-to" name="price-to" placeholder="price to" />
                     <h4>Find by name</h4>
                     <input type="text" style="width:95%;" id="find-by-name" name="find-by-name" placeholder="product name" />
                     <div class="clearfix"></div>
                     <h4>Find by manufacturer</h4>
                     <input type="text" style="width:95%;" id="find-by-manufacturer" name="find-by-manufacturer" placeholder="manufacturer name" />
                     <div class="clearfix"></div>
                 </div>
                 <div class="size">
                     <h4>Size</h4>
                     <ul>
                         <li><a href="#">XS</a></li>
                         <li><a href="#">S</a></li>
                         <li><a href="#">M</a></li>
                         <li><a href="#">L</a></li>
                         <li><a href="#">XL</a></li>
                     </ul>
                 </div>
              </div>
            <input type="submit" id="filter-product" style="margin: 0 auto;padding: 5px;width: 50%;background-color: black;color: white;border: none;font-weight: 400;border-radius: 5px;outline: none;margin-top: 1em;font-size: 1.2em;" value="Confirm">
         </div>
         <div class="clearfix"></div>
     </div>
</div>
</form>
<div>
            <c:if test="${countProducts > productMax}">
                <b> Pages :</b>
                <c:forEach var="i" begin="1"
                           end="${countProducts /productMax + (countProducts % productMax == 0 ? 0 : 1)}">

                    &#8199;<a href="products?page=${i -1}">
                    <c:out value="${i}"/>
                </a>
                </c:forEach>
            </c:if>
        </div>
```

Моя строка запроса в браузере, когда я нажимаю на кнопку confirm: `http://localhost:8888/products?sort=name&price-form=&price-to=&find-by-name=&find-by-manufacturer=`

Когда я нажимаю на ссылку на следующую страницу:

```
http://localhost:8888/products?page=1
```

Возможно в этом проблема? Как передавать все мои параметры вместе с нажатием на ссылку на пейджу?

Comment: при нажатии на сорт сохраняйте это в сессии, а не в параметрах

Comment: либо в ссылку передавайте и номер страницы, и направление сортировки